# coefficient not estimable model.matrix

Tags: r, linear-regression, model.matrix, limma

I'm making a de analysis using Limma, and I have a lot of samples. I trying to compute the design matrix and then the lmFit(). But when I call lmFit it returns

> coefficient not estimable

refering for the last coefficient in the design matrix. There were some NA values for some rows, so before to compute the design matrix i deleted them. This is the code:

```
delete = rownames(x$samples)[!complete.cases(x$samples)]
x$samples = x$samples[!rownames(x$samples) %in% delete,]
x$counts = x$counts[,!colnames(x$counts) %in% delete]

design <- model.matrix(~0+group+gender+y+age, data=x$samples)
colnames(design) <- gsub("group", "", colnames(design))
    v <- voom(x, design) 
    vfit <- lmFit(v, design)
```

where x is a DGE object. y is a numeric variable containing almost different values. So when i create the design matrix, it contains a lot of columns because the variable y has a lot of levels. So maybe I should create a new varaible y2 that divide the values in y in some categorie using `ifelse()` function.

Comment: Do one of your categorical variables (e.g. group, gender, y) have no observations (NAs or otherwise) in group or y or age? Also this question would be better suited on https://support.bioconductor.org/t/limma/

Comment: @TJGorrie yes, i fogot that i consider this case. I edit the post